# Don't include module in optimized script

Tags: requirejs, playframework-2.1, uglifyjs

I'm using play 2.1 and requireJs bundled with the framework.
I have some client javascript modules and some libraries (such as jquery, bootstrap, etc).

I want to get following combined/minified modules: main.js - for all my client scripts and libs.js - for all library scripts.

I created `libs` module (it's in coffeescript):

```
requirejs.config(
  paths:
    'jquery': 'jquery-1.8.3'
  shim:
    'jquery-ui-1.9.1':
      deps: ['jquery']
    'jquery.layout-1.3.0-rc30.74':
      deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui-1.9.1']
    'bootstrap':
      deps: ['jquery']
    'bootstrap-fileupload':
      deps: ['bootstrap']
)

define(["jquery", "jquery-ui-1.9.1", "jquery.layout-1.3.0-rc30.74",
  "bootstrap", "bootstrap-fileupload"],
->
  return {}
)
```

And somewhere in my client code I require libs module (I tried to provide it in dependency list and call `require("libs");`) but in production mode I get all my client code and libs combined in one `main.js` file.

Also I specified in `Build.scala` two modules:

```
    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
      requireJs += "main.js",
      requireJs += "libs.js",
      requireJsShim += "libs.js"
    )
```

How can I split them in production mode?
Thanks for any help! Have a good day!